# Search brings back results from Discussions but...doesn't

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, discussions-space

There is [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/mobile-dev/beta/discussions/77878692/i-want-to-create-an-app/77882385) which starts with

> Dear esteemed members of the Stack Overflow community,

[I searched for that text](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Dear+esteemed+members+of+the+Stack+Overflow+community%22) and was told that there was 1 result. But there was also no result displayed:

[image: Search page says "1 result" but the result list is empty]

Either I should be able to see a result or it should say that nothing was found.

---

Additional information about related problems:

[Jesse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/10601203/jesse) reported there is a similar issue with the network-wide search. [Searching Stack Exchange for "Dear esteemed members of the Stack Overflow community,"](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Dear+esteemed+members+of+the+Stack+Overflow+community%2C%22) still finds the discussion:

[image: Network search brings up this Q&A and the Discussion linked in the beginning]

The link for that result simply goes to `https://stackoverflow.com/`

Comment: (The trailing spaces (from (text) templates?) are still there in 2024. 786 trailing spaces in the source for that page.)

Comment: This also happens when [searching Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Dear+esteemed+members+of+the+Stack+Overflow+community%2C%22). There is actually a returned result there, but it just links to `https://stackoverflow.com` instead of the discussion.

Comment: @Jesse thank you, I've added this information to the post.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for the bug report. As intended, discussions are now excluded from both site and network search.

Comment: Wait… is it even possible to search Discussions now? Being able to search Discussions is important, but I don't see an obvious way to do so.

Comment: @cocomac Right now there is not a way to search Discussions. The best way to find posts about a topic is to use the tag filter on the main list page.