# Add Discussions to SE-wide search or, at least, SO search

Tags: feature-request, search, spam, discussions-space

Tl;dr - can Discussions be included in network-wide search, please? Failing that, can we have some other way to search Discussions?

[Berthold - CM said that right now there isn't a way to search Discussions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427880/search-brings-back-results-from-discussions-but-doesnt/428131?noredirect=1#comment987132_428131):

> @cocomac Right now there is not a way to search Discussions. The best way to find posts about a topic is to use the tag filter on the main list page.

This would be nice to have for Charcoal, as the ability to check for false-positive (i.e., not spam) search results [is important when deciding whether or not to watch/blacklist a keyword](https://charcoal-se.org/smokey/Guidance-for-Blacklisting-and-Watching#general-true-positive-and-false-positive-requirements). If [we're going to maybe get API access for Discussions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427471/support-programmatic-detection-and-flagging-of-spam-and-rude-abusive-content-in), search would be especially important to ensure the accuracy of watches & blacklists.

While tag filters are an option if I'm interested in finding posts about a topic, can actual search be added back? Specifically, the ability to search for an exact keyword in Discussions and "normal search" too. I'm somewhat more interested in using search for moderation-type actions than for actually finding posts about a topic.

Comment: Worth noting that the tag search doesn't help. It won't find mentions of a thing. Say, you want to find a word or phrase which isn't a tag. Even if we do end up trying to search for a technology or concept which is a tag - the tags aren't necessarily reflective of what the discussion is about. Random example which just happened to be one of the latest discussions [i am stuck with my android studio it fails to play url](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/78005892/i-am-stuck-with-my-android-studio-it-fails-to-play-url) mentions Android and shows Java code is tagged only [[tag:asp.net]].

Comment: When implementing this, please consider users that do not want to see discussions. For example, opting in using a flag, such as is done for collectives.

Comment: related: [Make Discussions posts available in SEDE](/q/427871/11107541)

Comment: also, [irony abounds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/392442/997587). "_\[the goal is that\] conversations can be easily accessible and discoverable in both the short term and long term_", "_previous conversations \[in chat\] are often hard to find_".

Comment: @ErikA it would make sense to follow the default behaviour searching `foo` will find questions and answers, `foo is:question` only questions, `foo is:answer` only answers `foo is:discussion` only discussions and maybe a new `foo is:all` any of these. Except the "all" that's how `is:article` works.

Comment: I think it'd generally be problematic for the search to by default return discussions along with questions, but i see no reason' we wouldn't want them to be returned if directly searching for them via is:discussion,

Comment: @KevinB Out of curiosity, what's your concern about inclusion by default...?

Comment: @cocomac personally - searching only Q&A has been the behaviour for all of the site's life. I have custom filters and bookmarks that rely on this. I don't know if there are other people or tools who monitor Q&A posts only with searches but I would expect there are. If Discussions are returned by default that would [break the workflow](https://xkcd.com/1172/) of many. Moreover, it is not even possible to amend it - there is no way to even get that functionality back (at present) because there is no search syntax or option to only return Q&A or exclude a category of posts.

Comment: @cocomac because this is a Q&A platform. It should prioritize Q&A, not a wanabe forum.

Comment: I would want the "other way" please. Discussions have no earthly business being in the search results for the main Q&A site. Just like meta posts have no earthly business being there.

Comment: @Gimby the post asks for them to be included in [the network-wide search](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22can+Discussions+be+included+in+network-wide+search%22). That one already returns meta posts.

Comment: @VLAZ What the heck. Today I learned.

Comment: @Gimby it's extremely useful. I use it quite a lot. would be nice if it had a search operator though.